# Campaigns not reported in Google Analytics SDK v2 on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

I've integrated Google Analytics SDK v2 on both Android and iOS and I am stuck on a campaign issue only with the iOS version of the SDK.
The setCampaignUrl works great on Android but completely does not report anything on a iPhone.

The tracker is correctly initialized since **all the other methods are working correctly** on iOS and I am doing it like the following:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker;
    if (tracker) {
        tracker.campaignUrl = [NSString stringWithCString:campaignUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
```

I've also tried setCampaignUrl:campaignUrl without success.

The campaign URL is the one given as example on Google Analytics web site ("utm_campaign=my_campaign&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=my_keyword&utm_content=ad_variation1") and do the job on Android.

Am I correctly using it, have you encountered a similar issue? Could it be a Analytics SDK issue?

Other developers reported the same issue on a Google group thread ( http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/sbUOYuhaMc8) which might mean that it could be a Google issue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, the documentation on Google Analytics web site is wrong **in the iOS part**:

The campaign URL given as example on Google Analytics web site ("utm_campaign=my_campaign&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=my_keyword&utm_content=ad_variation1") do the job on Android but **on iOS it has to be a well formatted web url** such as:

http://www.google.com?utm_campaign=my_campaign&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=my_keyword&utm_content=ad_variation1

to be reported on Analytics. They are certainly using a regex because any random site name would work and be careful, the site cannot contain "/" after the ".com"

Same for **setReferrerUrl:referrer** you cannot use a string like "google.com" or "myOtherApp" as mentionned by Google but instead a valid url such as "http://www.google.com" or "http://test.com/2"

Hope it helps